# Using Amazons AWS: mounting EBS on EC2 instance: 1 GiB appears as 414GB

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, amazon-web-services

Using Amazon's AWS, I created a 1 GiB volume. I attached it to a running instance and formatted it with ext3. I then mounted it and and used `df -h` to report its size. It's apparently 414G. I'm already using 2G of it.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that you tried to attach the volume to a device name that was already in use for ephemeral storage.

On some images I've used the boot device /dev/sda and /dev/sdb through /dev/sde is ephemeral storage.  When I tried to attach an EBS volume as /dev/sdb I received no error from the AWS management console, but the volume did not attach on /dev/sdb.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an error. :)

If you don't have any data on it, you might want to just ditch that volume and try again.